# On Collatz conjecture

Tags: probability, collatz-conjecture

I have seen Collatz conjecture  at  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture .  I  present  my  probabilistic approach:  Let $x$ denotes the random natural number. Let denote by $P(x)$ the probability that Collatz sequence starting at $x$ will return at 1.
If $x$ is divided to $2$ then  $x$ is sending to $x/2$ with probability $1/2$ and now  the probability that Collatz sequence starting at $x/2$ will return at 1 will be equal to $P(x/2)$
or

If $x$ is not divided to $2$ then  $x$ is sending to $3x+1$ with probability $1/2$ and now the probability that Collatz sequence starting at $3x+1$ will return at 1 will be equal to $P(3x+1)$.

Using total probability formula we get the following functional equation:$P(x)=1/2P(x/2)+1/2P(3x+1)$.
Notice that  each  constant  function satisfies  this  equation, i.e. $P(x)=c $ for each natural number $x$.  Taking into account that  $P(2)=1$ we deduce $c=1$.

Since  the probability that Collatz sequence starting at an arbitrary natural number will return to 1 is equal to 1 and there exists  only one Collatz sequence starting at each natural number I deduce that  Collatz Conjecture is valid.

**Question.** Where is mistake in this proof?

**P.S.** By probability measure  constructed in  [ Martin Sleziak, and Miloš Ziman. Lévy group and density measures, J. Number Theory, 128 (12), (2008), 3005–3012. MR2464850 (2009j:11019)] can be obtained equation mentioned above.

Comment: There are several suspicious claims in the above , but one caught my eye: the fact that any constant function satisfies that functional equation does not **necessarily** mean $\;P(x)\;$ *has* to be constant. Can you mend this?

Comment: Thank for help. This discussion is not correct. If for $n$ we denote by $P(n)$ probability that Collatz sequence starting at n will return at 1, then we get system P(n)=P(2n),P(2n+1)=P(6n+4),n=1,2,...  a.c.P(2)=1. It is clear that P(n)=1 or 0 for n in N. Notice P(n)=1 is solution of ths system but Collatz conjecture is that this system has no another solution.

Comment: "If x is divided to 2 then x is sending to x/2 with probability 1/2" No, there is no event of probability 1/2 in the picture here, only events of probability 0 and 1.

Comment: as $\mathbb{N}$ is infinite, a single exception will have probability weight 0, which is not excluded.

Answer (score 7):

"If $x$ divided to 2 then $x$ is sending to $x/2$ with probability 1/2." This statement does not capture the Collatz conjecture at all: if $x$ is even, it is *always* divided by 2. Whereas you're saying that with probability 1/2 it is divided by 2.

It looks like what you've written is: "pick a random number $x$ (nevermind that there's no uniform distribution on $\mathbb{N}$), then with probability 1/2 it is even and 1/2 that it's odd.

Now, you're right that $P(x)=\frac{1}{2}P(x/2)+\frac{1}{2}P(3x+1)$. But it's fallacious to conclude $P(x)$ is constant. Similar reasoning: $P(x)=P(x+1)$ implies $P(x)$ is a constant. False, $P(x)=\sin(2\pi x)$ works.

Comment: Dear Akex R.  Thanks! I agree with your comment presented on lines 4-5 and 6(with probability 0.6). You agree with me that equation is correct. The solution P(x) of this equation satisfies additional conditions : for example,P(2)=1, P(4)=1, an so on. $P(x)=c$ is the solution of this equation and satisfies this equation(I do not whether this equation has another solution satisfying these additional conditions. What I can say about $P(x)=P(x+1)$, it has various solutions. For example, $P(x)=C_1sin(2\pi x)+C_2$ for each $C_1,C_2 \in R$.

Comment: @GogiPantsulaia: Perhaps, if you formalize what it means for $x$ to be random in the integers. There's no uniform distribution, so presumably you'd need to prove the result for all finite intervals $[1,N]$.

Comment: Dear Alex R. We have that P(x):=mu(omega:Collatz sequence starting at  x(omega)will return at 1}=1 which implies that there is     a natural number n_0 such that for each n which is bigger than n_0  we have "Collatz sequence starting at  n will return at 1". Hence you are absolutely correct in your final part of your Answer 1.

Comment: Stating "Since the probability that Collatz sequence starting at an arbitrary natural number will return to 1 is equal to 1" is making the logical fallacy of assuming the conclusion *within* a (proposed) proof.